# ASP script to postion/rank based on totals

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

The code works in a way but if *R1Tots* are in a tie I want the *R1Tie* to reflect this

```
<%
Dim R1Tie
Dim R1Tots
R1Tots = (TLLB.Fields.Item("TotalSc").Value)
R1Tie = record.count
If R1Tots = R1Tots Then
R1Tie = R1Tie + 1
end if
%>

<%= R1Tie %>
```

Example of I need it to look like

```
::Pos:: ::Name:: ::TotalScore::
:: 1 :: ::Joe :: ::100::
:: 2 :: ::Jane:: ::90::
:: 2 :: ::Jeff:: ::90::
:: 4 :: ::Chip:: ::80::
:: 5 :: :: Jeb:: ::75::
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be both Classic ASP and ASP.net.  I'm assuming it's Classic ASP with VBScript rather than ASP.net with VB.net.

Presumably the code you have provided all sits inside a loop which iterates each result.  I think what you need to do is add 1 to the value of the position each loop, then subtract 1 from the displayed value if there is a tie.  I'd do this:

```
dim R1Position, R1Totalscore
R1Position = 0

do while not rs.eof
R1Position = (R1Position + 1)
If rs("TotalSc") = R1Totalscore then
    Response.write (R1Position - 1) & ":: ::" &  rs("name") & ":: ::" & rs("TotalSc") & "::<br>"   
Else
    Response.write R1Position & ":: ::" &  rs("name") & ":: ::" & rs("TotalSc") & "::<br>"
End If
rs("TotalSc") = R1Totalscore
rs.movenext
loop
```

Note that the last line in the loop assigns the current value of rs("totalsc") to R1Totalscore, in order for this value to be compared to the new value in the next iteration of the loop.

I realise this won't work if everyone has a score of zero.  I assume this isn't a scenario we need to worry about.

Comment: Yes i`m using Dreamweaver CS6 with access database. I have points in the database from users sometimes the points are a tie and i need to have a script to reflexed the tie example again::Pos:: ::Name:: ::Total Score::
:: 1 :: ::Joe :: ::100::
:: 2 :: ::Jane:: ::90::
:: 2 :: ::Jeff:: ::90::
:: 4 :: ::Chip:: ::80::
:: 5 :: :: Jeb:: ::75:: some reason your code is not working maybe i didn`t add correct info? Thanks